# Why did Freya suddenly get so agitated during her speech?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-huntsman-winters-war

Nearing the climax of [*The Huntsman: Winter's War*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2381991/), when Freya is holding a speech in front of her Huntsmen right before Eric tries to assassinate her, she suddenly starts to hesitate a little and gets somehow emotionally worked up, struggling to continue her actual speech. This seemed rather unexpected, especially if we consider her attitude towards emotionality.

So what caused that, **why did Freya suddenly get so agitated during that speech?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Freya saw her Huntsmen as her foster children.  At the moment of the speech she was coming to the realization that this wasn't her war, it wasn't the way she'd fight the war, and her sister was effectively sending her children to die.